# How Ruby Gem communication with active model of a particular model field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I am creating a gem named my_gem using the following command

```
bundle gem my_gem
```

that can perform some actions/events on, when an object access a, particular modal field.

The functionality which i want in my_gem
is refered from [act_as_voteable gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills, :interests
end
```

How to add the functionality so that i can perform the same.

> Let my Model is "User" and it has a field "option"
>
> whenever a coder write the line
>
> User.option
>
> The rails application should refers to my_gem to perform some action.

I thought there would be something like this coder can perform in its model.rb file so that Model signaled to refer my_gem

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  my_gem :option
end
```

e.g. just like we do

```
validates :title
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: And sorry for the question i have edited my question for mode elaboration.

Comment: @SohairAhmad the question is still absent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is just to extend the User Class by your module. You can do it directly or by some ruby monkey patching. Check out 
[taggable.rb#39](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/v3.4.1/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb#L39)
and the gem ebtry file
[acts_as_taggable_on#87](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/v3.4.1/lib/acts-as-taggable-on.rb#L87)

```
module MyGem::Extension

  def my_gem(option)
    #save the config in a class var
    @option = option
  end

  def option
    #check @option class var 
    #do work depedning on @option
  end
end


#the straight way
class User 
  extend MyGem::Extension
  my_gem :option
end


#the ruby magic way, extending all ActiveRecords
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  extend MyGem::Extension
end

class User 
 my_gem :option
end
```

Update: 
   There is a more detailed rails guide [The Basics of Creating Rails Plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-acts-as-method-to-active-record) which is doing the same thing by using ActiveSupport::Concern which is a syntactic sugar to extend class and instance methods at once.

Comment: If I try to access User.option, then firstly it will go to my_gem ? is it or not ?

Comment: if you extend the User by your gem module, it just imports all the module functions as class methods into the User class. So `def option` from your gem becomes just a regular User class method
See https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/v3.4.1/lib/acts-as-taggable-on.rb#L87

Comment: This is the nice concept thanks for this.My exact point is, let i want to do this `User.option.key=value` then this line should go to the my_gem's function that split `key=value` from `User.option`, what configuration should i do for `module MyGem::Extension

  def my_gem(option)
    #save the config in a class var
    @option = option
  end

  def option
    #chech @option class var 
    #do work depedning on @option
  end
end`

Comment: This is an other questiona and it's hard to understand with this little of information. I suggest you, first to try this concept with a basic Ruby class and ruby class methods without any modules, then rephrase and post a more specific question. Think exactly out how you would use the gem function from outside and provide the usage code. At the end just imagine, all you do on regular class can be extended into a module an the module can be extracted to a gem

Comment: Yes I implemented 
`include MyGem` into my User and passed `my_gem :option` and return `hello world` then it worked. 
I will surely come back with new question or will built my own logic. Thanks for your help. I appriciate this :)